(Flutter) S3 Upload/Download objects occurs SignatureDoesNotMatch when object key contains non-ascii character
When object key contains non-ascii character, there will be errors when uploading or downloading.
Even if encoding the object key by Uri.encodeComponent("テスト.jpeg"), the same error will still be reported.
Error message:
SignatureDoesNotMatch null: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provid Check your key and signing method.
Please is there any solution?
aws_s3_api: ^2.0.0

final s3Client = S3(
        region: region,
        credentials: AwsClientCredentials(
            accessKey: credentials.accessKeyId!,
            secretKey: credentials.secretAccessKey!,
            sessionToken: credentials.sessionToken));
    try {
      final contentType = await FileUtil.getFileContentType(filePath);
      final body = await File(filePath).readAsBytes();
      final objectResponse = await s3Client.putObject(
          bucket: "MyTestBucket",
          key: "テスト.jpeg",
          body: body,
          contentType: contentType);
      return filePath;
    } catch (e) {
      print('S3:::PutObject: $key failed, reason: $e');
      rethrow;
    }


